# Azure SQL sharding doesn't scale as expected

Tags: performance, azure

I have a web application developed for Azure Cloud Services using Azure SQL. I started with one database and using JMeter, I ran a load test from a dedicated virtual machine in the same Azure datacenter. The test plan was set up to test only one page, and only posting to that page (ignoring the initial get request).

My goal was to determine the max number of database transactions the app could handle per second. My first series of tests resulted in an average of 300 req/s using this test plan.

The page in question is accessing the following table:

```
create table [dbo].[Entries]
(
    [Id]                   int                 not null        identity(1,1)
    /* other columns here, about 10 in total */ 
);

alter table [dbo].[Entries] add constraint [PK_Entries] primary key ([Id]);
alter table [dbo].[Entries] add constraint [DF_Entries_Created] default(getutcdate()) for [Created];

create index [IX_Entries_EmailAddress] on [dbo].[Entries] ([EmailAddress]);
create index [IX_Entries_NACSZ] on [dbo].[Entries] 
(
     [FirstName]
    ,[LastName]
    ,[Address1]
    ,[City]
    ,[State]
    ,[Postal]
);
```

The page executes only two queries:

```
select 1 where exists 
(
    select 1 from Entries
     where EmailAddress = @EmailAddress
        or (
                    FirstName       = @FirstNAme
                and LastName        = @LastName
                and Address1        = @Address1
                and City            = @City
                and State           = @State
                and Postal          = @Postal
           ) 
);
```

and

```
insert into Entries
(
    ...
)
values
(
    ...
);

select cast(scope_identity() as int);
```

Performance testing on my machine (quad core, 8GB ram, local SQL 2012 express install) yields up to 800 req/s, so I was rather shocked to see a peak of about 300 req/s on Azure's servers. I chalked this up to resource contention on the database server, and added the necessary code to support sharding. The sharding mechanism uses a consistent hash on one of the key fields to determine which connection string to use (out of 3 possible, currently). The goal here was to split the database load across 3 Azure SQL databases and up the concurrency factor on the app.

I have verified that the sharding mechanism works (approximately equal number of entries end up in each database) and have stripped all non-essential code from the page so that all that is happening is the two queries noted above. I'm using the default isolation level (read commited) on the transaction. The final code looks something like this:

```
using (var db = ConnectToShard(keyToHash))
using (var tx = db.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
{
    // execute query 1
    // if result from query 1 is null, 
    //     execute query 2

    tx.Commit();
}
```

However, even with all this extra work, I can't seem to push the requests/sec above ~500 or so. My ideal target is 1000. I guess I'm missing something with regard to Azure SQL performance, but I'm not sure what. Any thoughts or suggestions for improving requests/sec?

Comment: Just out of interest, where are you running the code? On an Azure VM? What size is it?

Comment: Azure Cloud Service, have tried both Small and Medium instances. I was actually able to get remarkably higher numbers (1250 req/sec using 8 small instances or 2 medium instances) last night shortly after I posted this, but it was late and I'm not sure exactly what changed.

Comment: If the performance of the Azure SQL database degrades (perhaps you're sharing it with a noisy tenant), it can only swap to another instance with a new connection, so it's worth only keeping connections for a short duration - if that helps?

Comment: I was using PetaPoco before, and moved to directly using SqlConnection stuff. I think there was something in the PetaPoco code that was causing the issue, but I can't pin it down.